# Why do I get fifty rep for apparently doing nothing?

Tags: discussion

I did comment on a comment, but since what I wrote isn’t there, either I forgot to post it or it was deleted.  Neither of those would explain fifty points suddenly appearing as associated with that question.

Answer (score 2):

The only activity your account shows in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/101650/520) which has attracted five upvotes to date.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess I don’t know where to look for that.  So it’s just coincidence that five up votes happened about the time I made the failed comment attempt?

Comment: @WGroleau according to your [reputation history](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/41680/wgroleau?tab=reputation), the upvotes came about three weeks ago.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  So now the puzzle (not important, to be sure) is why they took three weeks to be displayed in other places.